# Android change Camera sound

Tags: android, audio, camera

i used the code for camera activity defined here:
[Android Save Image to SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713660/android-save-image-to-sd-card)

Can any one please help me how to change the default sound of camera, sounds are in raw folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sound is embedded in the systems source code for taking pictures. There doesn't seem to be any public facing API that is meant to disable / change the sound, so I think you are S.O.L.

As a user though if you are on a rooted device you can find the sound file that it plays and rename it something so that it will be unable to find the correct file to play, and thus won't make any sounds any time a picture is taken. If your app were running on a rooted device it could presumably just temporarily rename the file and fix it when done. But there would be a super user permission pop up when your app tries to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The camera API automatically plays a sound when takePicture() is called (and for video recording, when MediaRecorder.start/stopRecording() is called).

This behavior cannot be modified by normal applications, and the sound played cannot be changed to some other sound. This is in part due to privacy concerns.

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to play the sound in the Camera.ShutterCallback as described in this [link to the SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29).   I am unable to find the reference but I remember that there is a requirement to always play a sound when a photo is taken, this may mean that the default sound will always play.